# Android nav Bar ist overlapping Media Controller in Full Screen Mode

Tags: java, android, media-player, navbar, android-fullscreen

I've made a little fullscreen media player in Android Studio. When I tap on the media player in portrait mode, the media controller comes up. **But:** The navigation bar at the bottom also shows and overlaps the controller.

Do anyone know what I can do against that?

Thanks for help.

PS: Sorry for my bad english... If you can't understand something, just write a comment :D

Answer (score 0):

You can make the view fullscreen (hiding the navigation and status bars) by adding this to your MediaController Activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```